# My zend application is unable to upload files on youtube

Tags: php, zend-framework, youtube-api, gdata, gdata-api

I am using the following code to upload small and large videos on youtube. The code properly works on localhost but when I run it on server and upload the same videos, it uploads all the SMALL files but not the large files. Once upload is completed youtube shows following Error for files with large size:  Failed (unable to convert video file)

```
<?php
require_once 'Zend/Loader.php';
Zend_Loader::loadClass('Zend_Gdata_YouTube');
Zend_Loader::loadClass('Zend_Gdata_AuthSub');
Zend_Loader::loadClass('Zend_Gdata_App_Exception');
session_start();
$_SESSION['Key'] = 'My Developer Key';
?>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <?php

    if (!isset($_SESSION['sessionToken']) && !isset($_GET['token']) ){
        echo '<a href="' . getAuthSubRequestUrl() . '">Login!</a>';
    } else if (!isset($_SESSION['sessionToken']) && isset($_GET['token'])) {
      $_SESSION['sessionToken'] = Zend_Gdata_AuthSub::getAuthSubSessionToken($_GET['token']);
    }
    if(isset($_SESSION['sessionToken']))
    {
       $yt = new Zend_Gdata_YouTube(getAuthSubHttpClient());
       $myVideoEntry = new Zend_Gdata_YouTube_VideoEntry();

       $filesource = $yt->newMediaFileSource('myvideo.mov');
       $filesource->setContentType('video/quicktime');
       $filesource->setSlug('myvideo.mov');

    $myVideoEntry->setMediaSource($filesource);

   $myVideoEntry->setVideoDescription('this is my test video');

        $myVideoEntry->setVideoCategory("Music");

        $myVideoEntry->setVideoTitle('this is videoo');

        $myVideoEntry->SetVideoTags('tag1');


    $uploadUrl ='http://uploads.gdata.youtube.com/feeds/users/default/uploads';

    try {
        $newEntry = $yt->insertEntry($myVideoEntry,
                                     $uploadUrl,
                                     'Zend_Gdata_YouTube_VideoEntry');
    } catch (Zend_Gdata_App_HttpException $httpException) {
        echo $httpException->getRawResponseBody();
    } catch (Zend_Gdata_App_Exception $e) {
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }
    }

    ?>
</body>
</html>
<?php

function getAuthSubRequestUrl()
{
    $next = 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
    $scope = 'http://gdata.youtube.com';
    $secure = false;
    $session = true;
    return Zend_Gdata_AuthSub::getAuthSubTokenUri($next, $scope, $secure, $session);
}

function getAuthSubHttpClient()
{
    if (!isset($_SESSION['sessionToken']) && !isset($_GET['token']) ){
        echo '<a href="' . getAuthSubRequestUrl() . '">Login!</a>';
        return;
    } else if (!isset($_SESSION['sessionToken']) && isset($_GET['token'])) {
      $_SESSION['sessionToken'] = Zend_Gdata_AuthSub::getAuthSubSessionToken($_GET['token']);
    }

    $httpClient = Zend_Gdata_AuthSub::getHttpClient($_SESSION['sessionToken']);
    $httpClient->setHeaders('X-GData-Key', 'key='. $_SESSION['Key']);
    return $httpClient;
}

function updateAuthSubToken($singleUseToken)
{
    try {
        $sessionToken = Zend_Gdata_AuthSub::getAuthSubSessionToken($singleUseToken);
    } catch (Zend_Gdata_App_Exception $e) {
        print 'ERROR - Token upgrade for ' . $singleUseToken
            . ' failed : ' . $e->getMessage();
        return;
    }

    $_SESSION['sessionToken'] = $sessionToken;
    generateUrlInformation();
    header('Location: ' . $_SESSION['homeUrl']);
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a complete PHP example to upload large files.

```
    <?php

### TITLE: Resumable Uploads
### DESCRIPTION: <p>The code sample below calls the API's <code>videos.insert</code> method to add a video to user's channel. The code also utilizes <code>Google_MediaFileUpload</code> class with the <code>resumable upload</code> parameter set to <code>true</code> to be able to to upload the video in chunks.</p>
### API_METHOD: youtube.videos.insert

// Call set_include_path() as needed to point to your client library.
require_once 'Google_Client.php';
require_once 'contrib/Google_YouTubeService.php';
session_start();

/* You can acquire an OAuth 2 ID/secret pair from the API Access tab on the Google APIs Console
 <http://code.google.com/apis/console#access>
For more information about using OAuth2 to access Google APIs, please visit:
<https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2>
Please ensure that you have enabled the YouTube Data API for your project. */
$OAUTH2_CLIENT_ID = 'REPLACE_ME';
$OAUTH2_CLIENT_SECRET = 'REPLACE_ME';

$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setClientId($OAUTH2_CLIENT_ID);
$client->setClientSecret($OAUTH2_CLIENT_SECRET);
$redirect = filter_var('http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'],
    FILTER_SANITIZE_URL);
$client->setRedirectUri($redirect);

// YouTube object used to make all API requests.
$youtube = new Google_YoutubeService($client);

if (isset($_GET['code'])) {
  if (strval($_SESSION['state']) !== strval($_GET['state'])) {
    die('The session state did not match.');
  }

  $client->authenticate();
  $_SESSION['token'] = $client->getAccessToken();
  header('Location: ' . $redirect);
}

if (isset($_SESSION['token'])) {
  $client->setAccessToken($_SESSION['token']);
}

// Check if access token successfully acquired
if ($client->getAccessToken()) {
  try{
    // REPLACE with the path to your file that you want to upload
    $videoPath = "/path/to/file.mp4";

    // Create a snipet with title, description, tags and category id
    $snippet = new Google_VideoSnippet();
    $snippet->setTitle("Test title");
    $snippet->setDescription("Test description");
    $snippet->setTags(array("tag1", "tag2"));

    // Numeric video category. See
    // https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videoCategories/list 
    $snippet->setCategoryId("22");

    // Create a video status with privacy status. Options are "public", "private" and "unlisted".
    $status = new Google_VideoStatus();
    $status->privacyStatus = "public";

    // Create a YouTube video with snippet and status
    $video = new Google_Video();
    $video->setSnippet($snippet);
    $video->setStatus($status);

    // Size of each chunk of data in bytes. Setting it higher leads faster upload (less chunks,
    // for reliable connections). Setting it lower leads better recovery (fine-grained chunks)
    $chunkSizeBytes = 1 * 1024 * 1024;

    // Create a MediaFileUpload with resumable uploads
    $media = new Google_MediaFileUpload('video/*', null, true, $chunkSizeBytes);
    $media->setFileSize(filesize($videoPath));

    // Create a video insert request
    $insertResponse = $youtube->videos->insert("status,snippet", $video,
        array('mediaUpload' => $media));

    $uploadStatus = false;

    // Read file and upload chunk by chunk
    $handle = fopen($videoPath, "rb");
    while (!$uploadStatus && !feof($handle)) {
      $chunk = fread($handle, $chunkSizeBytes);
      $uploadStatus = $media->nextChunk($insertResponse, $chunk);
    }

    fclose($handle);


    $htmlBody .= "<h3>Video Uploaded</h3><ul>";
    $htmlBody .= sprintf('<li>%s (%s)</li>',
        $uploadStatus['snippet']['title'],
        $uploadStatus['id']);

    $htmlBody .= '</ul>';

  } catch (Google_ServiceException $e) {
    $htmlBody .= sprintf('<p>A service error occurred: <code>%s</code></p>',
        htmlspecialchars($e->getMessage()));
  } catch (Google_Exception $e) {
    $htmlBody .= sprintf('<p>An client error occurred: <code>%s</code></p>',
        htmlspecialchars($e->getMessage()));
  }

  $_SESSION['token'] = $client->getAccessToken();
} else {
  // If the user hasn't authorized the app, initiate the OAuth flow
  $state = mt_rand();
  $client->setState($state);
  $_SESSION['state'] = $state;

  $authUrl = $client->createAuthUrl();
  $htmlBody = <<<END
  <h3>Authorization Required</h3>
  <p>You need to <a href="$authUrl">authorize access</a> before proceeding.<p>
END;
}
?>

<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Video Uploaded</title>
</head>
<body>
  <?=$htmlBody?>
</body>
</html>
```