# Youtube API Thumbnails:set

Tags: php, youtube-api

I need some help on a youtube api called thumbnails:set.
I implemented oauth to my account, already a youtube partner and got a developer key.

I would want to know on how to use the HTTP request which is "POST https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/thumbnails/set" with videoId as its parameter and implement it in php.

In general, I would like to know how to upload a custom thumbnail and pass it using the API towards youtube.

here's the link of the api: https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/thumbnails/set#try-it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [YouTube php client library](https://code.google.com/p/google-api-php-client/). You will use

> $setResponse = $youtube->thumbnails->set("YOUR_VIDEO_ID",
>           array('mediaUpload' => $media));

where media is your media upload as in

> ```
> $media = new Google_MediaFileUpload('image/*', null, true, $chunkSizeBytes);
> $media->setFileSize(filesize($videoPath));
> ```

The rest of the code will be OAuth2. You can always use the framework I introduced as an answer to [My zend application is unable to upload files on youtube](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17460369/my-zend-application-is-unable-to-upload-files-on-youtube/17594638#17594638)

Comment: $chunksize = 2*1024;
$media = new Google_MediaFileUpload('images/*', null, true, $chunksize);
$imagepath = "sample_image.png";
$media->processFileUpload($imagepath,'image/*');
$media->setFileSize(filesize($imagepath));
$insertResponse = $youtube->thumbnails->set("video_id", array('mediaUpload' => $media));
$media->process($insertResponse,$chunksize);

I've done it this way, there are no errors but when I refresh my channel the custom thumbnail won't appear. How should I do this correctly?