# PHP:Youtube API thumbnails.set

Tags: php, youtube-api, google-api-php-client

whenever i run this one i get an error saying

Undefined property: Google_YouTubeService::$thumbnails
Fatal error:  Call to a member function set() on a non-object

```
$searchResponse= $youtube->thumbnails->set("videoId",array('mediaUpload'=>$media, 'videoId'=>'CAc2JyONesI'));
```

what's wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your call should be like

> $setResponse = $youtube->thumbnails->set("YOUR_VIDEO_ID", array('mediaUpload' => $media));

Besides that, you may have initialized $youtube object wrong, check with the [sample answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17460369/my-zend-application-is-unable-to-upload-files-on-youtube/17594638#17594638).

Most likely you are using an older version of the client library, that doesn't have Thumbnails class in it. Please download latest library from [here](https://code.google.com/p/google-api-php-client/).

Comment: I downloaded the latest library but i'm still getting these errors. help!

Comment: As I explained in the side note. We will cut a new built of the library. I'll update this thread once it's out.

Comment: today or tomorrow, there will be a new public build.

Comment: It's updated https://code.google.com/p/google-api-php-client/downloads/detail?name=google-api-php-client-0.6.3.tar.gz

Answer (score 0):

> Thumbnails object (Side note, I realized latest library built doesn't have thumbnails object in it, will update it as soon as we can.) -Ibrahim Ulukaya

I need this too. When will the library be updated?

Comment: today or tomorrow, there will be a new public build.

Comment: It's updated https://code.google.com/p/google-api-php-client/downloads/detail?name=google-api-php-client-0.6.3.tar.gz

Comment: Hi @ibrahim-ulukaya, I've done this so far but my thumbnails won't update.
`code`
$chunksize = 2*1024;
  $media = new Google_MediaFileUpload('images/*', null, true, $chunksize);
  $imagepath = "sample.png";
  $media->processFileUpload($imagepath,'image/*');
  $insertResponse = $youtube->thumbnails->set("2mbfucN2yYM", array('mediaUpload' => $media));
`code`